# script sharp gadgets in 0.5.5.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, script#

I just created a new project with Script Sharp 0.5.5.0 VS2010 template for the sidebar and it did not even compile.
It fails saying Application.Current.Run is not valid anymore. (Method Run doesn't exists)
What would be the recommended solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScriptHost.Run - its a bug in the project template... hope to have a fixed project template + some gadget fixes in a couple of days.

Edit on 12/25/09 - Just posted 0.5.6 build of script# with fixes for the gadget scenario.